# How to clip Transition Animation to draw only with in the Child view?

Tags: android, android-animation

I am running a transition animation for a view in an activity to come from top of the screen to bottom. which is coming on top of the title view of the screen. How can i apply the animation only with in the view(respective to child only) or from a specific Y or X position?

I am using the below code

XML Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator">
<translate android:fromYDelta="-100%p" android:toYDelta="0" android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

Java Code

```
Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(_activity, R.anim.in_from_top);
view.setAnimation(in);
```

Now this view is coming from the top of the screen. I want the animation to be started at specific X,Y point instead of top of the screen. The animated view is coming on top of the Title of the Activity which is a flaw as per my requirement.

Comment: I did changes to my question.

Comment: Any one respond to my question......

Answer (score 0):

If you have added the two childrens to a single parent then this issues occurs. Add the children to an another layout and then add this layout to the actual layout. This will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try animation from java code only as

```
Animation animation1=new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f, 250.0f);
animation1.setDuration(5000);
view.startAnimation(animation1);
```

and you can set your X and Y coordinates in `TranslateAnimation(fromX, toX, fromY, toY)` as I have done in above code.